# Правильно ли расставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

"Есенин очень ценит свое время и даже если уделяет его другим, рассматривает это как щедрый подарок со своей стороны, за который ему должны быть благодарны".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом предложении не хватает запятой перед "даже": "Есенин очень ценит свое время и, даже если уделяет его другим, рассматривает это как щедрый подарок со своей стороны, за который ему должны быть благодарны". Придаточное предложение "даже если уделяет его другим" находится внутри главного, поэтому его необходимо обособить. Союз И соединяет сказуемые ЦЕНИТ и РАССМАТРИВАЕТ в главном предложении.

Answer (score 1):

После И  надо поставить запятую, т.к. начинается придаточное предложение (даже если...). Перед И запятая не нужна, так как И соединяет однородные сказуемые: ценит и рассматривает

Comment: Екатерина, мы с Вами ответили секунда в секунду.

Comment: Отлично, я об этом же сейчас думаю.)))